# Static IP configuration failed in NODEMCU

Tags: esp8266, wifi, nodemcu

I'm trying to connect NODEMCU to my home network and set static IP address, but the static IP didn't set properly this is the code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.config(IPAddress(192,168,1,129), IPAddress(192,168,1,1), IPAddress(225,225,225,0));
  WiFi.begin("Bam", "123456789");
  Serial.print("\nConnecting");
  while(WiFi.status()!=3){
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println("Connected");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

and this is the output on the Serial monitor:

```
13:28:46.715 -> Connecting.......Connected
13:28:50.937 -> 192.168.1.100
```

when I set the same static IP address to my phone it sets with no problem.

Comment: You connect to the WiFi first, then try to change the IP, of course it will not work. Config first, then connect.

Comment: @hcheung I forgot to mention all solutions I've tried, I tried this but didn't work

Comment: Shouldn't the network mask be 255.255.255.0 rather than 225.225.225.0 ?
Also does anything else on your network have an IP of 192.168.1.129 ?